# React Native App, How to run on browser? its not a expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I created a React Native App, **It not Expo project,** so how can I run in the browser, it is running well in Android mobile and Android Emulator, **my react native app created using React Native Cli.**

Comment: Are you also using [React Native Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)?

Comment: @zero298: No, I'm not using React Native Web.

Comment: thank you for response,

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the browser for React Native development, unless you are sure you won't be needing ANY native mobile functions. When called in the browser you will get warnings and errors about unavailable methods.

Comment: so how could I test my React Native app for Web ?

Comment: I am not sure what it is you are asking as you have replied to the original post with that you don't use React Native for Web.